# Update individual files in Xcode 4.4 SVN

Tags: xcode, svn

I could select individual file when 'update' in SVN project in Xcode 4.3.
I could review which files were changed and committed.

But after I upgraded Xcode to 4.4, when I click 'File > Source Control > Update' from menu bar or click 'Update' in Organizer, no updated files list comes out and just tiny updating slide comes down.
It updates whole changed files without my selection.

I know I can update specific file by right clicking it and select 'Source Control > Update Selected Files' but I want to review the whole changed files in one window like before Xcode 4.4.

How can I do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want to do "Update..." instead of "Update".

You can get that to show up under File-->Source Control and holding down the control key.

It looks like in XCode 4.4. the default source control options have been switched around as follows:

**Xcode 4.4+** - default = "*Update*"

"*Update*" (Cmd+Opt+X) - Silently updates all files unless there is a merge conflict that needs to be manually corrected

"*Update...*" (Ctrl+Cmd+Opt+X) - Updates all files allowing you to verify/merge updated files

**Xcode 4.3** - default = "*Update...*"

"*Update...*" (Ctrl+Cmd+Opt+X) - Updates all files allowing you to verify/merge updated files

"*Update All*" (Cmd+Opt+X) - Silently updates all files unless there is a merge conflict that needs to be manually corrected

Comment: Silent update should purely and simply not exist ! This is bad. Making this silent option the default is worse. Having menus that changes by pressing key ??? Who designed this software ? Certainly a person who never worked in team. Anyway +1 and thank you very much for the info. I would never have found this one (it's been 1 day I was looking for it).

Comment: Important note about _Update..._ (control+option+command+x) in Xcode 6: this more interactive update will log file names modified and time stamp in Log Navigator. Silent _Update All_ (option+command+x) does not!

Answer (score 0):

This is again broken in XCode 4.5. Silently will update all files, ignoring your selected files. It doesn't matter if you control-click or right-click or File->Source Control... whatever the way you select it, xcode will update the whole project.
Bad, bad Apple!