# To Get XCode SVN to Show Updates Before Updating

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, svn

I am using XCode's **GUI** SVN to manage a repository. I know you can see the changes before updating in commandline. Can one enable it in the GUI SVN management as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found out.

Just simply, you can press CTRL + ALT(Option) + COMMAND + X.

In Xcode 4.3 and older, we dont need press "CTRL" but from 4.5 we need.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12190542/1579262